# WebServlet - urlPatterns with two chars

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, annotations

I'm using `WebServlet` annotation something like below:

```
@WebServlet( urlPatterns = {"/en", "/de", "/fr"})  
public class GeoServlet {  
 // servlet code goes here  
}
```

As you can see I need to define every single geo in the URL, but instead of that I want to say something like `allow all patterns from a-z but limit the pattern by two chars`

for example something like:

```
@WebServlet( urlPatterns = {"/[a-z]"}{2}  )
```

How can I achieve this? tnx.

Comment: Hope it is possible. IMHO No.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to do that. The [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)  defines the syntax of mappings

> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a `‘/’` character and ending with a `‘/*’` suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a `‘*.’` prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string (`""`) is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form
>     `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In this case the path info is `’/’` and
>     the servlet path and context path is empty string (`““`).
> - A string containing only the `’/’` character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>     request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

It doesn't recognize regular expressions.

Consider using a [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) which internally has its own mapping.